# Using Underscore with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm having problem getting Underscore working with ReactJS. I get following error when I run my ReactJS class:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined`

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
var MyBox = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        console.log(_.difference([1,2,3], [2,4,6,7]));
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyBox />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

The error is very obvious, it simply don't understand what is _ sign. My question is that even if I have already imported the underscore library in `index.html` file why I still get this error? Is it possible to use underscore inside of ReactJS? I think it should work because jQuery is also working there and I didn't have to define `$` of jQuery in order to use it. I simply imported the jQuery library and it worked immediately.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to `require("_")`?

Comment: @The Unfortunately I can't use `require()` due to project limitations. Otherwise this would have definitely worked. Even if I can use it I get following error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: I don't know React, but maybe you missed _browser.min.js_ ?

Comment: @Max Sorry I forgot to add it in my code here but it was used in my project and still get the same error.

Comment: On the browser console watch if there are any errors on network (maybe your firewall, proxy, etc blocking the request ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that your `main.js` gets executed before Underscore is loaded.

Try moving the Underscore include to the top of your list of scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This actually solved the problem. It seems that it had to be loaded before `react.js` and `react-dom.js` libraries. I wonder why because jQuery is working normally with `$`. Thank you for your answer :)